# WebGrid in Partial View - Stop paging from reloading page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I have a dashboard type page which contains multiple partial views each of which contain a webgrid.

For example this is web grids is  in my _CurrentSubscriptions partial view:

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.Titles,
    rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
    defaultSort: "Name",
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "UserSubscriptions");
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("Name"), grid.Column("Description"),
grid.Column(format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveSub")</text>)));
```

I also have an _addSubscription partial view which contains the following grid to show search results.

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.Titles,
    rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
    defaultSort: "Name",
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "TitlesFound");
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("Name"), grid.Column("Description"),
grid.Column(format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddSub")</text>)));
```

Both partial views are called from my Subscriptions/index.cshtml

**Is it possible to restrict the paging on each of the grids from reloading the page and just update the selected grid?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your grid in a div with an Id.
2. (You have already done this) When you instantiate the grid, specify the AJAX parameter
   ajaxUpdateContainerId with the div's Id.
3. Reload your page.
4. Click another page and notice there is no page post back; only the grid reloads.

   ```
   <div id="UserSubscriptions">
       @grid.GetHtml(columns: 
           grid.Columns(grid.Column("Name"),
           grid.Column("Description"),
           grid.Column(format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddSub")</text>)));
   </div>
   ```